# MongoDb and C#, collection returns type but not all properties

Tags: c#, mongodb

im working on a function that fetches an object from mongoDb. As of now, it returns the correct type and all properties except one. This property has a backing field and i think that is what is causing the trouble. This is the exception i get when i try to look at the property:

'Foo.Properties' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'

But i can see that the document looks as it should in my db.

Here is what my find method looks like:

```
public Foo FindSingleFoo(Guid accountId, Guid fooId)
        {
            var collection = GetCollection();

            var query = Query<Foo>.EQ(x => x.Id, FooId);

            var foo = collection.FindOneAs<Foo>(query);

            return foo;
        }
```

The Foo type property that isn't correct looks like this:

```
private readonly ISet<Guid> _properties = new HashSet<Guid>();

public IEnumerable<Guid> Properties
        {
            get
            {
                return _properties.ToList();
            }
        }
```

I have a BsonClassMap:

```
public class FooMap : BsonClassMap<Foo>
    {
        public FooMap()
        {
            AutoMap();

            MapField("_properties")
                .SetElementName("Properties");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you add a setter to your Properties property? I don't think the deserializer has a way of accessing the private backing property to be able to set the value as you are expecting.

Comment: Tried it but when i looked at the property i got this exception: {"Value can't be null.\r\nParametername: source"}

Comment: Can you post the code change that includes the setter which caused the exception you mention above?